# PowerShell type cast using type stored in variable

Tags: .net, powershell

I'd like to cast a .NET object to another .NET type, but:

- The target .NET type (class) is stored in a variable
- I don't want to use the `-as` PowerShell operator
- I am using complex, non-primitive types

How would you achieve this?

For example, this is the "PowerShell" way to do it, but I don't want to use `-as`:

```
$TargetType = [System.String]; # The type I want to cast to
1 -as $TargetType;             # Cast object as $TargetType
```

Unfortunately, this does not work:

```
$TargetType = [System.String];
[$TargetType]1;
```

.. because PowerShell does not allow the use of variables inside the square brackets, in this scenario.

I am imagining something like:

```
$TargetType = [System.String];
$TargetType.Cast(1); # Does something like this exist in the .NET framework?
```

Can it be done with .NET method syntax? Is there a static method that does this?

Comment: Whenever someone says "X works but I don't want to use X". I instantly think of an XY Problem situation. What is your actual goal and why does the -as method not work for you?

Comment: I agree with your sentiment. The reasoning behind the question is that I try to ensure that my PowerShell coding can translate to C# (and other, similar languages) as closely as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can roughly emulate a cast using the following method:

```
[System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives]::ConvertTo($Value, $TargetType)
```

A true cast may behave differently than the above method for dynamic objects that provide their own conversions.  Otherwise, the only other difference I can think of is performance - a true cast may perform better because of optimizations not available in the ConvertTo static method.

To precisely emulate a cast, you'll need to generate a script block with something like:

```
function GenerateCastScriptBlock
{
    param([type]$Type)

    [scriptblock]::Create('param($Value) [{0}]$Value' -f
        [Microsoft.PowerShell.ToStringCodeMethods]::Type($Type))
}
```

You can then assign this script block to a function or invoke it directly, e.g.:

```
(& (GenerateCastScriptBlock ([int])) "42").GetType()
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have clarified this in the question a bit more. Is there a way to do it more generically, without relying on the PowerShell managed libraries?

Comment: That's a very different question.  Programming languages define valid conversions.  For example, conversions in PowerShell or C++/CLI can be different than what C# might allow.  I think you need to specify what exactly you want to convert generically before looking for a simple API that does what you want.

Comment: I forgot that C# had an `as` operator. I guess maybe my question was asked in vain. I thought that I had previously come across an API that did what I was looking for, but it may have been something slightly different. Marking yours as the answer for now.

Comment: Your solution was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you use the GenerateCastScriptBlock to assign the value to a variable? E.g. how do you assign the value of 42 to a variable, say, $x? And would it be possible to do the same for arrays? Say, convert a string '@("x","y","z")' to an array type variable $y.