# Why is my script block treated as a string on execution instead of being executed as a script?

Tags: powershell

I expected the following script blocks to execute and return numbers of type `byte` and `int` but everything inside quotation marks becomes just a string instead of a script.

```
$a=(&{Param($t);"[$t]`$num=10;`$num+=2;`$num"} byte)
$a
# OUTPUTS STRING [byte]$num=10;$num+=2;$num
# NOT NUMBER 12

$ty="int"
$b=(&{"[$ty]`$num=5;`$num+=2;`$num"})
$b
# OUTPUTS STRING [int]$num=5;$num+=2;$num
# NOT NUMBER 7
```

How do I make it work as expected?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you wrap in quotes (see [about_quoting_rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules)) you are creating a string:

```
"[$t]`$num=10;`$num+=2;`$num"
```

Because that's what you are assembling, that is what is being returned.

---

I assume you are trying to cast to a specific type (int/byte):

```
[$t]`$num=10
```

You can instead use the [`LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.languageprimitives.convertto?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) Method as it will do this for you:

```
[System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives]::ConvertTo(Object, Type)
```

I would define the script block first, then invoke it separately:

```
$a={ codehere }
& $a param1 param2
```

Taking all that onboard:

```
$a={Param($t,$num);$num=[System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives]::ConvertTo($num, $t);$num+2}
& $a byte 5
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement [James C.'s helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51952829/45375), which explains the problem well and contains a solution with limitations<sup>[1]</sup>, with *alternative solutions*:

Script blocks used in isolation are indeed like anonymous functions (and they're also the foundation of scripts and named functions).

While **a *cast* / type-constraint with a *non-literal* type name isn't possible**, you can **use the `-as` operator to similar effect**:

```
PS> & { param($t) $num = 10; $num+=2; $num -as $t } byte # !! use -as $t on OUTPUT
12  # type is [byte]
```

**Caveats**:

- Unlike PowerShell casts, the `-as` operator is *culture-sensitive* - for certain types, but not others: e.g., it is culture-sensitive for `[datetime]`, but not for `[double]`

  - These problematic inconsistencies are discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8129).
- If conversion isn't possible, `-as` quietly returns `$null`, so you may have to handle that case explicitly.
- Because `-as` cannot be used to *type-constrain* a variable, subsequent operations can change the value's data type.

  - This is indeed what would happen if you did `$num = 10 -as [byte]` followed by `$num += 2`: The addition would implicitly change the type to `[int]`.
  - Therefore, apply the `-as` operator on output, or, if necessary, on each intermediate operation.

    - Beware of compound operators such as `+=`, where `-as` won't work as intended; instead of `$num += 2 -as [byte]`, use `$num = ($num + 2) -as [byte]`, for instance.
- As an aside: *if* `New-Variable` supported type-constraining, it would be an alternative, along the lines  of `New-Variable -Type $t -Name num -Value 10`; it currently doesn't (as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core 6.1.0), but it [may in the future](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7566).

---

Alternatively, **create your script block *from a string representation* with `[scriptblock]::Create()`**, which allows you to "bake" the type name into the string:

```
PS> & ([scriptblock]::Create('[{0}] $num=10; $num+=2; $num' -f 'byte'))
12  # type is [byte]
```

**Caveats**:

- Only use this techniques on strings whose content you either fully control or trust, given that arbitrary commands can be constructed this way.
- Additionally, in the interest of maintainability, this technique is only suitable for small pieces of code.

---

<sup>[1] [`[System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives]::ConvertTo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.languageprimitives.convertto) isn't fully equivalent to a cast, because it doesn't cover ["dynamic objects that provide their own conversions."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22796417/45375)</sup>